# How to add custom tooltip for google map marker ?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to show some nice tooltip with image and text on mouse hover of google maps marker. 
marker.setTitle - works only with text but not with html 
Does google maps api have standard solution ? 
Can you please suggest lib to create tooltips and make them look nice ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did on a project if you want a DIY solution.

1. Create a hidden div on your page with css position set to absolute. Make sure your DIV appears on top of your map container (z-index).
2. Bind mouseover and mouseout events to your markers to trigger a showDiv / hideDiv function.
3. When mouse hovers a marker, get the mouse x,y position, set the DIV top and left css values accordingly and set its css to display:block;
4. When mouse is out, hide the DIV again.

This way you can really control how your "infowindow" appears and what it will contain. Good luck.

Comment: If you handle the mouseover event of the marker by using google.maps.event.addListener, all the event object contains is the lat and long, so you don't get the mouse's x,y positions. That renders this approach impossible to implement.

Comment: I didn't say you get the mouse position from the marker listener. Get it from the DOM as you would do in any other script.

Answer (score 3):

You could listen for the `mouseover` event on the marker, and trigger an [`infoWindow`](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow) to appear with that event.

Once you have the infowindow, you can put pictures and text in it in a way that is well supported by the api.

Comment: yes, but infoWindow is hard to customize. It has predefined design. InfoBox is proffered for me.

Answer (score 0):

Oleg, why are you you bound to the google maps api. You can inject a custom tooltip into the DOM.

Attach event listeners for mouseover, mousemove and mouseout listeners on the map (or specific parts of the map). Each of those listeners also gives you an argument giving you the mouse coordinates.

Use a fixed/absolute style on the tooltip's css for positioning it

on mouseover, inject the tooltip at the cursor position into the DOM
on mousemove, update the position (left and top)
on mouseout, remove the tooltip from the DOM.

I've recently built this for google maps polygons. You can repurpose my approach for any other part of your map since almost every feature on the google map supports events.

link: https://medium.com/@asimmittal/custom-tooltips-for-google-maps-in-pure-javascript-a8004b8e9458