# hover-over tooltip callback (for google maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, tooltip, title

TL;DR: How can I create the text for hover-over tooltips on google maps on the fly just as they are hovered-over?

More detail:

I'm making google maps markers in (what I think is) the usual way:

```
var mar = new google.maps.Marker({
  position:loca.loc,
  map:map,
  title:formatTitle(data[i]),
  icon:"i/"+returnColors(loca.lang)+"_"+"10.png"
});
```

But I'm stuck because my map is in more than one language, so I want to display the tooltip in language A or language B based on a setting in the page.  I've been able to configure all my other stuff (for example, InfoWindows, etc) by simply setting callbacks and at the moment when the display is called, I see which langauge we're using and I show the appropriate text.

The thing is that I want my hover-over tooltips (titles) to be in either langauge too.  Nevertheless, I haven't figured out what callback (if any) is getting triggered when a tooltip gets displayed.  As I've written the code above, the marker gets created when the map loads and the tooltip along with it.  I want some way to generate the tooltip/title on the fly as the hover-over occurs.

Thanks for any tips!

EDIT:

One commenter downvoted the question without knowing the answer so that seems a little weird and made me think that perhaps I'm not being specific enough.

Some event fires in the browser code to indicate that it's time to display the tooltip at such-and-such coordinates.  I want to override that event, if necessary.

Clearly there's some code somewhere which dislays that text, I want to find that code and potentially override it.

Hopefully that helps clarify what I'm asking.  I don't need it to be a method in the google.maps.* class hierarchy, I just need to be able to display the text dynamically.

Perhaps some other hover-over/tooltip is the way to go, I've done this some years ago with CSS pseudo-classes but surely there's some modern approach someone can recommend.

Comment: There isn't a callback for the `title` property.  You can implement your own custom rollover text that works the same way as your other "stuff" is implemented.

Comment: related question: [How to add custom tooltip for google map marker ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581045/how-to-add-custom-tooltip-for-google-map-marker)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the related question, I'll take a look at it.  But why downvote the question if you don't know the answer?  Maybe I just don't understand the way things are supposed to work in this voting system.

Comment: Think too this downvote was a little bit harsh and mysterious, especially when the suggested "related question" not are answering the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold the reference to a marker in a variable, you can always change the title dynamically with `setTitle()`.  Here a simple example where the title of a marker is modified when the value of a select box is changed :

```
document.getElementById('lang').onchange = function() {
    var dynamicTitle = this.value == 1 ? 'english title' : 'danish title';
    marker.setTitle(dynamicTitle);
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8w1rfjn4/**

Obviously you dont have to use a select box, you can use any event that suit your needs.